# Library is being skipped during compilation, even though it is in the correct directory

Tags: c, gcc, networking, linker, winsock2

I wrote a c networking program (a server) in Codeblocks using the Winsock2 library. I was able to link the library file, libw2_32.a, and compile the program in Codeblocks. However, I made a second c program (a client) that I wanted to run at the same time, so I needed to compile these programs with the command line.

I am running the command `gcc -L ...\lib32 -l ws2_32 main.c -o main -Wall` to compile the program. The compiler starts to search the given file directory, but when it checks the correct library file "libws2_32.a" it says: `skipping incompatible ...\lib32/libws2_32.a when searching for -lws2_32`. It returns the same error on then next line when it checks the same file with a \ instead of a . The main function is the main function of the server application, but the same error occurs when I try to complile the main function of the client application. I just started with the server application so that the client has something to which to connect.

I am confused how it can search the correct file but it is still incompatible. What is the correct way to compile this?

Comment: `...` -> `..` ???

Comment: Craig Estey, I was just using the three dots to shorten the command. I am actually using the full file directory: C:\TDM-GCC-64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib32.